# Замена элементов в массиве Delphi

Tags: delphi, функции, циклы

Есть условие задачи:

> Исходный одномерный целочисленный массив задаётся в диалоговом режиме, в окне списка, в виде набора строк.
>   Составить программу замены первого отрицательного элемента массива суммой положительных элементов.
>   Если замена невозможна, то вывести сообщение об этом. В противном случае вывести элементы преобразованного массива
>   во второе окно списка, в виде набора строк.

Я не совсем понимаю условие задачи, а конкретно:

Что значит, массив задаётся **в диалоговом режиме, в окне списка, в виде набора строк?**

Замена невозможна только в случае, когда все элементы массива отрицательные?

Что значит вывести элементы преобразованного массива **во второе окно списка, в виде набора строк.**

Answer (score 1):

Массив не нужен.

Форма, на ней два `TMemo` и кнопка. В первое мемо вводятся строки: каждая строка целое число. Во второе мемо выведется результат. По нажатию кнопки, идем по строкам первого мемо, переводя каждую строку в целое - `StrToInt`. Накапливаем сумму положительных чисел. Запоминаем индекс первого отрицательного. Потом идем по строкам первого мемо еще раз, перенося строку за строкой во второе мемо, по запомненному индексу выводим сумму - `IntToStr`.

Замена невозможна в случае, когда все элементы массива положительные.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать это на примере, а то не совсем понимаю?

Comment: @Igor вы же видите, что это учебное задание. Раз нужно решение через массив, значит он нужен. (Если все лепить в обработчик нажатия кнопки в Форме, то будет негибкий код. По хорошему, надо в Форме парсить ввод, а обработку делать функцией - вот для нее массивы и нужны)

Comment: Не подскажите, как именно это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Igor если это учебное задание, то ТС "думать как надо" еще просто не умеет. Сделав как в ответе, ТС получил бы у меня по шапке, за бизнес-логику в обработчике формы и доп.задание - повторить всё в консольном приложении с переиспользованием кода.